# How to combine asynchronous method with synchronous method in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm calling from the main method:

```
public MainPage()
{
  Text_to_Speech.changetospeech("Welcome to Nepal!", newmedia).Wait();
  mytxtblck.Text="Hello from Nepal!"
}
```

What I really want to do is `Wait` until "Welcome to Nepal" is being spoken and then write "Hello" in `mytextblck`.

I've gone to several threads and worked, but nothing could make it work.

```
public async static Task changetospeech(string text, MediaElement mediaa)
{
   var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
   var voices = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices;

   synth.Voice = voices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Female );
   SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

   MediaElement media = mediaa;
   media.SetSource(stream,stream.ContentType);
   media.Play();   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like what you really want is to trigger the text change when the [`MediaEnded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended(v=vs.110).aspx) event is fired.

You *could* do that within your `ChangeToSpeech` method, although it'll be a little ugly:

```
public async static Task ChangeToSpeech(string text, MediaElement media)
{
    var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    var voices = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices;

    synth.Voice = voices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Female);

    SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    RoutedEventHandler handler = delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(10); };
    media.MediaEnded += handler;
    try
    {
        media.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        media.Play();
        // Asynchronously wait for the event to fire
        await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        media.MediaEnded -= handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't `Task.FromResult` better than `TaskCompletionSource`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: How exactly would you use that to solve the problem at hand? How would it help you to asynchronously wait for an event to fire?

Comment: `Task<int> returnTask = Task.FromResult<int>(0);`
`returnTask = Task.FromResult(10)`;
`await returnTask`

Will do same stuff

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: No it won't. That will *immediately* complete, making the await pointless. The whole point of using the TCS is that we can set it in the event handler. Again, how does your solution help us to asynchronously wait for `media.MediaEnded` to fire? (That's the whole point of the code, really...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Got it thanks, I was under the impression that `Task.FromResult` is a replacement of `TaskCompletionSource`, but now it looks good only for mocking and unit tests

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: No, it's also good for cached situations etc. Anywhere that you want to create a task that you already know the result of... whereas you use `TaskCompletionSource` for situations where you want to create a task now, and you'll populate the result (or fault) later.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes that's what mocking would be, especially for testing Async methods

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: I didn't say it *wasn't* useful for mocking... but there are plenty of situations where you might have a value already in *production* code. Imagine a computing cache, which you can ask for a value - it could return `Task.OfResult` if it had the value already, or call an actual async method if it needed to compute the result.

Comment: @JonSkeet got it thank you so much for providing details